# Returning a value from an Async Function. AWS/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm trying to build a component that retrieves a full list of users from Amazon AWS/Amplify, and displays said results in a table via a map function. All good so far.

However, for the 4th column, I need to call a second function to check if the user is part of any groups. I've tested the function as a button/onClick event - and it works (console.logging the output). But calling it directly when rendering the table data doesn't return anything.

Here is what I've included in my return statement (within the map function)

`<td>={getUserGroups(user.email)}</td>`

Which then calls this function:

```
const getUserGroups = async (user) => {
    const userGroup = await cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminListGroupsForUser(
      {
        UserPoolId: '**Removed**',
        Username: user,
      },
      (err, data) => {
        if (!data.Groups.length) {
          return 'No';
        } else {
          return 'Yes';
        }
      }
    );
  };
```

Can anyone advise? Many thanks in advance if so!

Answer (score 0):

Because you should never do that! Check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) React doc for better understanding of how and where you should make AJAX calls.

There are multiple ways, how you can solve your issue. For instance, add user groups *(or whatever you need to get from the backend)* as a state, and then call the backend and then update that state with a response and then React will re-render your component accordingly.

Example with hooks, but it's just to explain the idea:

```
const [groups, setGroups] = useState(null); // here you will keep what "await cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminListGroupsForUser()" returns

useEffect(() => {}, [
    // here you will call the backend and when you have the response
    // you set it as a state for this component
    setGroups(/* data from response */);
]);
```

And your component (column, whatever) should use `groups`:

```
<td>{/* here you will do whatever you need to do with groups */}</td>
```

For class components you will use lifecycle methods to achieve this (it's all in the documentation - link above).